# Fetch data in array's order

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, promise, fetch

I have an array which contains a list of IDs. With it, I'm trying to fetch some posts data from the WordPress REST API. I managed to retrieve the data I was looking for, but the issue I'm running into is that the objects inside the array generated by the `map` function are not in the same order as the IDs in the original array.

```
fetchData = async () => {
    const array = [];
    await Promise.all( ids.map( async id => {
        await apiFetch( {
            path: `/wp/v2/posts/${ id }`,
        } ).then( response => array.push( response ) );
    } ) );
    console.log( array );
};
```

How can I ensure that the fetched data is retrieved and stored in the same order as the original array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making asynchronous calls so responses won't be fetched in order.

Instead of an array, you can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with `id` as key and `response` as value.

```
fetchData = async () => {
    const map = new Map();
    await Promise.all( ids.map( async id => {
        await apiFetch( {
            path: `/wp/v2/posts/${ id }`,
        } ).then( response => map.set(id, response) );
    } ) );

    // Display responses in 'ids' array order.
    ids.forEach(id => {
      console.log(map.get(id));
    });
};
```